# Try Catch, number in a text field

Tags: c#, try-catch

I made a winform that draws data from a database in SQL, to search I have Combo Boxes - cboField and cboOperator and I am using txtValue. The form is about cars, when I put in (cboField) Payment (cboOperator) = (txtValue) Ford it crashes. How do i put something in to stop it from doing this and the other way round, e.g. Make of car = 5

```
    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboField.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (cboOperation.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (txtValue.TextLength == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        string filter;
        filter = "[" + cboField.Text + "]";

        filter += cboOperation.Text + "'" + txtValue.Text + "'";

        tblCarBindingSource.Filter = filter;
```

This is the click event for the Run button

it says Evaluation Exception was Unhandled on the last line of my code i pasted

Comment: Could you please write down fragments of your code to clarify your question?

Comment: the question is not very clear.  code would be clearer, as would details about the exception that happens when it crashes

Comment: Do you even make sense to yourself as what your talking about? Plus where exactly in the provided code the exception is thrown?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Also from what I understand, in such scenarios it is highly recommended to use "strongly-typed" functionality.

Comment: @zenwalker - If you read the last line you would see where exactly it's thrown

Comment: I think you need a space after the last bracket and a space before the first quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to prevent the user from putting something like "5" in your text fields because it causes your data binding source filter to throw an EvaluateException?

Hard to tell exactly what you're looking for but if that's the case, try something like this:

```
try
{
    tblCarBindingSource.Filter = filter;
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid values in your text fields.");
}
```

Comment: Yes that's right, It's working fine now but when I say that Payment = Ford it says Cannot perform operation "=" on System.Decimal and System.String, I'm trying to make it bug proof

Comment: Okay, if you have no need to handle different exceptions differently, then just remove the specific Exception type. I have edited the code to catch all exceptions instead.

Comment: Just be aware that you may want to handle different exceptions differently down the road...just keep it in mind. That's why I put it in, it's good practice.